# React Native MapView is not Scrolling, Zooming In Out. So how can i achieve it?

Tags: react-native, maps, react-native-maps

I have tried it with all the possible solution like onreasonchange , and many

```
 <MapView style={styles.map}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        ref={ref => { this.map = ref; }}
        mapType={MAP_TYPES.TERRAIN}
        initialRegion={this.state.region}

    onRegionChange={region => this.onRegionChange(region)}
    scrollEnabled={true}
    rotateEnabled={true}
    showsUserLocation = {true}
    followUserLocation={true}
    zoomEnabled={true}
    zoomControlEnabled={true}
    loadingEnabled={true}
    pitchEnabled={true}
    showsIndoorLevelPicker={true}
```

But it is not working, I am currently doing testing in android.
Is there any solution for this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove  **...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject**  from your MapView container's style.

Answer (score 0):

I got working it by removing ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject from style.